# ¿Cómo acceso al campo Data de mi Json? C#

Tags: c#, json, api

Tengo una API que me devulve los siguientes datos:

> {"Result":200,"Message":"Ok Successful","Data":{"IDUser":3,"Name":"Daniel Angeles","IDCustomer":1,"CustomerIdentification":""}}

Y quiero acceder al campo Data para construir un objeto de la clase:

```
public class DatosOperador
{
        public int IDUser { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int IDCustomer { get; set; }
        public string CustomerIdentification { get; set; }
}
```

Hasta ahora tengo esto y pude separar Result, Message y Data, pero no doy con cómo igualar Data a un objeto:

```
var json = await responseLoginAPI.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    dynamic? obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
```

Agradezco su ayuda.

Comment: Te esta devolviendo un json que tiene result, Message y Data (como string).. y depues podes volver a transformar data en tu clase... no uses dynamic.. no hay nada dinamico ahi...

Comment: Tal vez te interese esto [Procedimiento para serializar y deserializar JSON en .NET](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to?pivots=dotnet-6-0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo te recomiendo esta [pagina](https://app.quicktype.io/) para que conviertas tu JSON a clases

y de esta manera será más fácil de mapear tu JSON, tu clase quedara de esta manera

```
public class Response
    {
        [JsonProperty("Result")]
        public long Result { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("Message")]
        public string Message { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("Data")]
        public Data Data { get; set; }
    }

    public class Data
    {
        [JsonProperty("IDUser")]
        public long IdUser { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("IDCustomer")]
        public long IdCustomer { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("CustomerIdentification")]
        public string CustomerIdentification { get; set; }
    }
```

para que puedas acceder a tu JSON, deserializas de esta manera

```
var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(json);
```

y de esta manera accedes a tus datos, como IDUser o Name

```
Console.WriteLine(response.Data.Name);
```

aqui te dejo el [ejemplo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/74K6uX) para que puedas revisarlo